# iPhone 4 volume is really quiet

Tags: audio, iphone

I have a used iPhone 4 with 16GB of memory in it, running IOS 7.1.2. The problem with this iPhone is that the volume is really quiet whenever i'm playing music or making a call and setting the caller on the speaker.

The volume is currently at it's max (by tapping the buttons on the side).

[image]

*Note: I haven't used the "broken" iPhone for this screenshot, this was just for showing what I did to increase the volume to the max.*

I have tried rebooting the device a couple of times already, this didn't work.

What do (or can) I have to do to make the speaker play at a decent volume again? Do I have to replace it?

Comment: do you have some non apple sound applications installed ? if not your sound card or speaker is broken.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Nope, the iPhone is wiped. Can you please edit into an answer? I now know what to do! :)

Answer (score 1):

For Music anyways, check your EQ in the Music tab of Settings. Some sound quieter then others and vice versa.

For Speaker Phone I'm not so sure, but as a universal problem it may be Volume Limit, also found in the Music tab of Settings.

Comment: This didn't work, the sound stays the same. Could it be the hardware?

Answer (score 1):

My partner's iPhone is extremely quiet and tinny sounding (mine is not). I believe this to be blocked speaker holes - I can just about see what looks like chocolate blocking them! Is it possible that this is your cause?

Comment: I've looked in the speaker and all i could see was just a tiny bit of dust. I cleaned that out by just blowing in it, it was just so little, so i dont think that would make a difference.